# JSLint is not available in my PyCharm

Tags: javascript, pycharm, jslint, jshint, jetbrains-ide

I am new to PyCharm, and I tried to enable a JavaScript Code Quality Tool by referring [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/jslint.html?origin=old_help) guide.

I am using `pycharm-community-2016.1` and I couldn't find JavaScript listed under Languages and Frameworks.

- Do I need to install a specific version to do this?
- Is there any plugin like thing which I can install now to enable JS code quality tools?

Comment: I can't even find Languages and Frameworks in my version.  I am assuming that this is only available in the paid edition, though.